# How to find all entries with reference to yourself?

Tags: postgresql

I have table with id and parent_id fields and I want to show all entries with reference to yourself, something like this:

```
select * from mytable where id=parent_id;
```

How to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with the query you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with an inner join:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable m1
INNER JOIN mytable m2 ON m2.id = m1.parent_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply **Self Join**
select * from mytable a,mytable b where id=parent_id;